# Spring <form:password> does not remember the value in multiform wizard

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-session

I'm using a password field in Spring `<form:password>` tag like below,

```
<form:input path="extBtsBaseDto.extBtsRedmineConnectionDto.basicPassword"/>
```

Which I'm using to get the password from the user in a screen which is a part of many other screens. These screens work as a wizard and I use Session to hold the values at my main screen DTO. The password I have mentioned above is bind in an inner DTO.

**The problem**: Suppose I have password field in screen A when I navigate by submitting the data from screen A to B, I can get the password at B but in next the screen it vanishes from the DTO.

I can solve the problem by replacing the Spring `<form:password>` tag by normal HTML tag but wondering why this is happening and would like to use Spring tag if there is any solution to this.

If anyone wants to see my code I can share. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you saving the value in a java object and putting it in the session? Or just passaing the form to the next request?

Comment: Saving data in Java object in session.

Answer (score 5):

Have you already tried using

```
showPassword
```

attribute of  tag?
Default is false, try to set true:

```
<form:password showPassword="true" path="extBtsBaseDto.extBtsRedmineConnectionDto.basicPassword"/>
```

[docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-passwordtag)